# Fondo se adapte a dispositivos de diferentes tamaños en CSS

Tags: css

Estoy trabajando en un sitio web y he configurado una imagen de fondo usando CSS. Sin embargo, la imagen parece demasiado grande en dispositivos móviles y se corta. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la imagen de fondo se adapte automáticamente al tamaño de la pantalla, de manera que se vea bien en dispositivos de diferentes tamaños? ¿Hay alguna propiedad CSS específica que deba utilizar para lograr esto?
Código CSS actual:

¿Qué ajustes debo realizar en el CSS para lograr este objetivo? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Para responder tu pregunta yo debo generar un código de ejemplo, que puede o no ser parecido a lo que tu tienes (tengo que adivinar). Entonces, para facilitar la vida a las personas que desean ayudarte, debes incluir tu HTML+CSS en tu pregunta, para esto presionar [edit] y agrégalo